# neovim init.lua module "lua.plguins" not found

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm in the configuration neovim
I added the configuration file in C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua

```
require("lua.plugins")
```

and C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\lua\plugins.lua

```
return require('packer').startup(function()
use "wbthomason/packer.nvim"
end)
```

After the start-up neovim

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:1: module 'lua.plugins' not found:
    no field package.preload['lua.plugins']
    no file '.\lua\plugins.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua\lua\plugins.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua\lua\plugins\init.lua'
    no file '.\lua\plugins.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua\plugins.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\lua.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

May I ask why

I tried to install Lua test the require

```
scoop install lua
```

C:\Users\wupan\code\lua\test.lua

```
require("hello")
```

C:\Users\wupan\code\lua\hello.lua

```
print("hello world")
```

There are also problems

```
C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\lua\current\lua54.exe: .\test.lua:1: module 'hello' not found:
    no field package.preload['hello']
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\lua\current'
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\lua\current'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    .\test.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem analysis

Let's use the following example which you gave us:

`C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua`

```lua
require("lua.plugins")
```

`C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\lua\plugins.lua`

```lua
return require('packer').startup(function()
    use "wbthomason/packer.nvim"
end)
```

And now let's take a look into your error message:

```lua
    no file 'C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua\lua\plugins.lua'
```

The important part is the **`bin\lua\lua`** thing here. It's because your
`require("lua.plugins")` starts to look up a directory in one of your runtime
path (see `:h rtp` for more information).

### Solution

You just need to fix your content in
`C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\init.lua` to:

```lua
require("plugins")
```

because then neovim will look up a directory which is named `plugins` in
`C:\Users\wupan\scoop\apps\neovim\current\bin\lua` for example, since its in
your runtime path.

### Little note

You can change your content from
`C:\Users\wupan\AppData\Local\nvim\lua\plugins.lua` to:

```lua
require('packer').startup(function()
    use "wbthomason/packer.nvim"
end)
```

or how I did it:

```lua
local packer = require('packer')

packer.startup(function(use)
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
end)
```

That makes it a little bit more readable in my opinion :)